# React Can't fetch to array

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to fetch data and put it in an array so i have created an array in my state called

lokalen[]

then i do

```
 fetch('http://localhost:3001/Lokalen/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({lokalen:data}))
console.log(this.state.data)
    }
```

but my array seems to remain empty
i have checked that the right things are fetched and yes they do, if i use
console.log(data) in the second then i can see the required data in my log.
i just can't get it in my array.

Anyone who has any idea why? the fetch is being done in componentdidmount

Comment: would it be possible the data gets in the array to late because its a promise it needs to forfill? is there a way to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to get a file that is already on your machine.
When you use Localhost, you are hosting the server on your local machine.

When you use `fetch()` , just specify the path of the file/API endpoint

from The [FETCH](https://github.github.io/fetch/)
 documents you could do something like this

```
fetch(/Lokalen/, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
 },
  credentials: "same-origin"
}).then(function(response) {
  response.status     //=> number 100–599
  response.statusText //=> String
  response.headers    //=> Headers
  response.url        //=> String

  return response.text()
}, function(error) {
  error.message //=> String
})
```